# Issues creating trigger in Azure DataFactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm working to create a TumblingWindowTrigger that specifies a schedule parameter so that I can execute a backfill of data. After executing the PowerShell command below, in the UI I see a new trigger with the correct name, however, it is of type: "Trigger" and not associated with my pipleine named 'appevents_daily'. I don't see any errors or warnings. Any thoughts on what I'm missing ?

PowerShell Commnads:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount 
$ResourceGroupName="treasuredata"
$DataFactoryName="treasured"
$TriggerName="BackfillAppevents"

Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $TriggerName -DefinitionFile "C:\Users\rajesh\Source\datafactory\backfill.json"
```

The file backfill.json is defined as:

```
{
  "name": "BackfillAppevents",
  "properties": {
    "type": "TumblingWindowTrigger",
    "typeProperties": {
      "frequency": "Hour",
      "interval": 24,
      "startTime": "2018-04-09T19:00:00.000Z",
      "endTime": "2018-05-04T23:26:00.000Z",
      "delay": "00:00:00",
      "maxConcurrency": 1,
      "schedule": {
        "minutes": [0,15,30,45]
      },
      "retryPolicy": {
        "count": 3,
        "intervalInSeconds": 120
      }
    },
    "pipeline": {
      "pipelineReference": {
        "referenceName": "appevents_daily",
        "type": "PipelineReference"
      },
      "parameters": {
        "windowStart": "@trigger().outputs.windowStartTime",
        "windowEnd": "@trigger().outputs.windowEndTime"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the root issue was an out of date commandlet. FYI -- to install the latest in Powershell:

```
Install-Module -Name AzureRM.DataFactoryV2 -Force
```